# Angular sample code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create the sample angular application, where I have initialized an angular application and rendering a list defined in the controller, but I am not getting anything in output, and even not getting any error in javascript console.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="ListController as listctrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in listctrl.list">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
angular
  .module('myApp',[])
  .controller('ListController', function($scope) {
    var listctrl = this;
    var list = ['A','B','C','D'];
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have **`listctrl.list`** instead of **`var list = ['A','B','C','D'];`**

```
 listctrl.list = ['A','B','C','D'];
```

**DEMO**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="ListController as listctrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in listctrl.list">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
angular
  .module('myApp',[])
  .controller('ListController', function($scope) {
  
    var listctrl = this;
    listctrl.list = ['A','B','C','D'];
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```